# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una consulta con tres tablas?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una base de datos en la que están estas tablas con los siguientes campos:

- Tabla **USUARIOS**: ID_USUARIO, NOMBRE, APELLIDOS
- Tabla **ALUMNOS**: ID_USUARIO, ID_ALUMNO, ID_TUTOR
- Tabla **PROFESORES**: ID_USUARIO, ID_PROFESOR

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que engloba tres tablas. En la tabla **USUARIOS** tengo los datos y tengo que filtrar por el **ID_USUARIO** que lo tengo en la tabla **ALUMNOS** y en la tabla **PROFESORES**.
La consulta que tengo hasta ahora, me muestra ahora mismo los **ID_USUARIO** de los alumnos junto con los **ID_USUARIO** de su tutor o profesor. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT a.ID_USUARIO ID_U_A,p.ID_USUARIO ID_U_P FROM ALUMNOS a INNER JOIN PROFESORES p ON a.ID_TUTOR = p.ID_PROFESOR;
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar en vez del **ID_USUARIO** de ambos, el **NOMBRE** y el **APELLIDO** de los mismos. Estos se encuentran en la tabla **USUARIOS**. ¿Sabéis cómo se expone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya se está obteniendo los ids de alumno y profesor, podemos hacer una sub consulta donde obtenemos la propiedad que queremos que en este caso es el nombre y el apellido.

```js
SELECT 
  (SELECT CONCAT(u.NOMBRE, ' ', u.APELLIDOS) FROM USUARIOS u WHERE u.ID_USUARIO = a.ID_USUARIO) AS nombre_completo_alumno,
  (SELECT CONCAT(u.NOMBRE, ' ', u.APELLIDOS) FROM USUARIOS u WHERE u.ID_USUARIO = p.ID_USUARIO) AS nombre_completo_profesor
FROM ALUMNOS a 
  INNER JOIN PROFESORES p ON a.ID_TUTOR = p.ID_PROFESOR;
```

También podemos relacionar la misma tabla usuarios con profesor y alumno, y así obtener las propiedades que queremos.

```js
SELECT 
  ua.nombre AS nombre_alumno, ua.apellidos AS apellidos_alumno,
  up.nombre AS nombre_profesor, up.apellidos AS apellidos_profesor
FROM alumnos a 
  INNER JOIN profesores p ON a.id_tutor = p.id_profesor
  INNER JOIN usuarios up ON up.id_usuarios = p.id_usuario
  INNER JOIN usuarios ua ON ua.id_usuarios = a.id_usuario;
```

Comment: La función CONCAT() solo admite dos argumentos de entrada. He sustituido los CONCAT() por u.NOMBRE || ' ' || u.APELLIDOS. De todas formas, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @Robinson, las respuestas que tienen solo código, sin una explicación de cómo o por qué ese código resuelve la pregunta son generalmente consideradas de baja calidad. Sugiero que edites la respuesta y agregues, al menos, una breve explicación. Para más información, lee [answer]. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El problema se resuelve casi como lo has planteado en lenguaje natural. Es decir, puedes hacer `join` dos veces a la tabla usuario, una vez para obtener los datos del profesor y otra vez para obtener los datos del alumno.

Para diferenciar entre las dos veces que aparece la tabla, nos velemos de ponerle un alias a cada aparición. Entonces, partiendo de la consulta que ya tienes, agregamos los dos nuevos joins.

Paso a paso, primero como quedaría la cláusula `from`:

```
  from ALUMNOS a 
       inner join PROFESORES p on a.ID_TUTOR = p.ID_PROFESOR
       inner join USUARIOS ua on ua.ID_USUARIO = a.ID_USUARIO
       inner join USUARIOS up on up.ID_USUARIO = p.ID_USUARIO
```

Aquí, ahora, `ua` es la tabla `USUARIO` en su aparición como *usuario del alumno* y `up` es la misma tabla `USUARIO`, pero esta vez en su aparición como *usuario del profesor*.

Ahora, obtener los nombres, resulta trivial, el el select:

```
select   ua.NOMBRE||' '||ua.APELLIDOS NombreAlumno
       , up.NOMBRE||' '||up.APELLIDOS NombreTutor
  from ALUMNOS a 
       inner join PROFESORES p on a.ID_TUTOR = p.ID_PROFESOR
       inner join USUARIOS ua on ua.ID_USUARIO = a.ID_USUARIO
       inner join USUARIOS up on up.ID_USUARIO = p.ID_USUARIO
```